# Can we pass partition as parameter in stored procedure ? I'm getting following error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can we pass partition as parameter in stored procedure ? I'm getting following error.
Please help on this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME (PARTITION_NAME IN VARCHAR2)  
     IS  
    LASTDATE VARCHAR2(12);  
ENDDATE VARCHAR2(12);  
BEGIN  
IF PARTITION_NAME='DEC_2014' OR PARTITION_NAME='JAN_2015' OR   PARTITION_NAME='MAR_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='MAY_2015' OR   PARTITION_NAME='JUL_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='AUG_2015' OR   PARTITION_NAME='OCT_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='DEC_2015' OR   PARTITION_NAME='JAN_2016' THEN
ENDDATE:='31';
ELSIF PARTITION_NAME='NOV_2014' OR PARTITION_NAME='APR_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='JUN_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='SEP_2015' OR PARTITION_NAME='NOV_2015' THEN  
ENDDATE:='30';  
ELSE  
ENDDATE:='28';  
END IF;  
LASTDATE:=CONCAT(CONCAT(ENDDATE,'-'),REPLACE (PARTITION_NAME, '_', '-'));  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LASTDATE);  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PARTITION_NAME);  

UPDATE  
  /*+ PARALLEL(Alias 4) */  
  TABLE_NAME PARTITION (PARTITION_NAME) Alias  
SET Alias.Alias_D_EFFECTIVE_DATE =  
  (SELECT  
    /*+ PARALLEL(Alias3 4) */  
    ALAIS2.ALAIS2_D_DATETIME  
  FROM schema1.TABLE_2 ALAIS2  
  WHERE TRUNC(ALAIS2_D_DATETIME) <= TO_DATE(LASTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')  
  AND ALAIS2.ALAIS2_N_TRN_ID                     = Alias.Alias_N_PR  
  )  
WHERE EXISTS  
  (SELECT Alias3.ALAIS2_D_DATETIME  
  FROM schema1.TABLE_2 Alias3  
  WHERE TRUNC(Alias3.ALAIS2_D_DATETIME) <= TO_DATE(LASTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')  
  AND Alias3.ALAIS2_N_TRN_ID                         = Alias.Alias_N_PR  
  );  

COMMIT;  
END PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

Error:

Error at line 1
ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist
ORA-06512: at "schema1.PROCEDURE_NAME", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: You need dynamic sql - `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  
  /*+ PARALLEL(Alias 4) */  
  TABLE_NAME PARTITION ('||PARTITION_NAME||') Alias  
SET Alias.Alias_D_EFFECTIVE_DATE =  
  (SELECT  .....';`

Comment: Basic rule, you cannot use variables in compiled code in place of an IDENTIFIER. In those instances dynamic SQL is required.

Comment: Also, consider this logic to replace that bulky IF statement :)    `lastdate := to_char(last_day(to_date('01_'||partition_name, 'dd_mon_yyyy')), 'dd-mon-yyyy'); `

Comment: Why do you feel you need to specify the partition name?

Comment: Building on what @Ditto says, make `lastdate` a `date` and then drop the the `to_char` from the assignment and `to_date` calls in the query.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: good point, I didn't see him using it in the query and converting ;) save the back and forth conversion ...

Comment: @Bob As i need to do the update only to the specific partition

Comment: I suggest that you allow the database do its job. It will determine the correct partition for you. I have any number of extremely large partitioned tables with a large number of partitions on them that I work with, and I *never* code a partition clause on any SQL statement. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do by Dynamic SQL Statements, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement

follow this link ... 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME (PARTITION_NAME IN VARCHAR2)  
     IS  
    LASTDATE VARCHAR2(12);  
ENDDATE VARCHAR2(12); 
query_str VARCHAR2(1000); 
BEGIN  
//.......your code.......
query_str := 'UPDATE TABLE_NAME PARTITION (' || PARTITION_NAME || ') Alias ' 
            ||'SET Alias.Alias_D_EFFECTIVE_DATE =.....'  

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str;
COMMIT;  
END PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

Hope this will work.